Ocultar carpetas home en sftp en debian
He configurado un servidor sftpd en debian, para que los usuarios loguen a home pero queden enjaulados, la configuracion funciono, cada usuario puede ver y editar lo suyo, lo unico que quiero es que cuando el usuario se logue, quede dentro de su carpeta pero no pueda ver la de los demas, a pesar de que no tengan acceso a estas, no me parece bien que las vean, se podra hacer algo?
Esta la configuracion que tengo sshd_config
Match group prueba
ChrootDirectory /home/
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
AllowAgentForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /%u
PermitTunnel no
PasswordAuthentication yes

y asi se ve.

las que están con símbolo de interrogación son las que no quiero que se vean.

Para evitar que los usuarios vean las carpetas de otros en SFTP, ajusta la configuración de ChrootDirectory para que cada usuario quede "enjaulado" en su propio directorio.
Cambia la línea ChrootDirectory en sshd_config:
Match group prueba
ChrootDirectory /home/%u
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
AllowAgentForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PermitTunnel no
PasswordAuthentication yes

Asegúrate de que la estructura de permisos y propiedad esté correcta:
El directorio /home/usuario debe ser propiedad de root y tener permisos 755.
El subdirectorio donde trabajará el usuario (e.g., /home/usuario/archivos) puede ser propiedad del usuario y tener permisos adecuados.
Con esta configuración, cada usuario solo verá su propio directorio y no podrá acceder ni visualizar los directorios de otros usuarios.

wow, oye quien eres? hice lo que me dijiste y funciono perfecto, muchas gracias!! le admiro y respeto.
